# Pandas how to make group by without losing other column information

Tags: python, pandas

I've a df like this

```
      source  destination  weight  partition
0          1            2     193          7
1          1           22    2172          7
2          2            3     188          7
3          2            1     193          7
4          2            4     403          7
...      ...          ...     ...        ...
8865    3351         3352     719          4
8866    3351         2961    6009          4
8867    3352         3351     719          4
8868    3353         1540     128          2
8869    3353         1377     198          2
```

which is a edge list of a graph, partition is source vertex's partition information.
I want to groupby source with their destinations to find all neighbours
I tried this

```py
group = result.groupby("source")["destination"].apply(list).reset_index(name="neighbours")
```

and result is:

```
      source          neighbours
0          1             [2, 22]
1          2           [3, 1, 4]
2          3                 [2]
3          4          [21, 2, 5]
4          5              [4, 8]
...      ...                 ...
3348    3349  [3350, 3345, 3324]
3349    3350              [3349]
3350    3351  [2896, 3352, 2961]
3351    3352              [3351]
3352    3353        [1540, 1377]
```

but here as you can see I'm losing partition information
is there a way to keep this column as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need grouping by 2 columns use:

```
group = (result.groupby(["source", "partition"])["destination"]
               .apply(list)
               .reset_index(name="neighbours"))
```

If need first value of column `partition` aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `first`:

```
group = (result.groupby("source")
               .agg({'partition':'first',"destination": list})
               .reset_index(name="neighbours"))
```